# Edge detection based on point

Tags: contour, edge-detection

I have to do image processing for the x-ray image as shown below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1QBk.png).

In particular, if you specify a point such as a red dot, the edge that passes through it must be extracted.
There are a lot of edges in the image, but I just have to extract the edge (yellow line) that point passes, and I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: are it only the outer edges or can it also be bone edges ?

Comment: @BennoGeels also inside..! but the edge that abstract by the normal canny edge detection.

Comment: Have a look at what is called "intelligent scissors".